# Horizontal scrollbar bug when minimising window

Tags: html, css

I'm encountering some difficulty with some CSS I'm coding.

Whenever I minimise the window a horizontal scrollbar appears and the problem with this scrollbar is that it doesn't go away even when I maximise the window.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.header_bg {
    background-color: #F1F1EE;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #738ebe;
    width: 100%;
}

.header_main {
    width: 960px; // would it be better to change this to width: 80%
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header_main img {
    float: left;
}

.header_main div {
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header_bg">
    <div class="header_main">
        <img src="resources/img/login_logo.png" width="163" height="66" />
        <div>Already a member? Sign in</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Fiddles: [Edit mode](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/782fc/), [full width](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/782fc/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
.header_bg {
    background-color: #F1F1EE;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #738ebe;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is adding to the calculated width of it's container, ie, `body`, which `header_bg` is stretching to fit `100%`, so the padding is shifting `body`s dimensions beyond the viewport, thus triggering `scroll-x`.

Remove it and your scroll bar goes away:

```
padding: 10px 0;
```

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/782fc/2/

Full: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/782fc/2/embedded/result

Or, alternatively, put the `width` on the `body` with `margin: 0 auto;` so it auto-centers:

```
body {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

...

.header_bg {
    background-color: #F1F1EE;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #738ebe;
    width: 100%;
}

.header_main {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/782fc/4/

Full: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/782fc/4/embedded/result/

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/782fc/5/ ([Full view](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/782fc/5/embedded/result/))